# Prometheus quantile aggregation fails

Tags: prometheus

the following query worked for us just fine:

```
sum(http_request_duration_microseconds{role="api",service="awesome-api",environment="prod"}) by (quantile)
```

But now it complains like:

```
Error executing query: parse error at char 98: unexpected <aggr:quantile> in grouping opts, expected identifier
```

Running the query without `sum(...) by (quantile)` has *quantile* in every metric included.

Information about the prometheus we're running:

```
Version     1.1.1
Revision    24db241bd556fd45854dd310692ac291de7d24e1
Branch      master
BuildUser   root@90d3f69e2d67
BuildDate   20160907-09:42:10
GoVersion   go1.6.3
```

Is this some outdated PromQL or are we missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, thus query is invalid mathematically - you can't add up quantiles. If you want to aggregate use Histograms and histogram_quantile.

Secondly this is a recent regression. We're about to push a fix for this. See https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/1958